# Unable to visualize word count plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, text-mining

I have a tidy document term matrix that I have successfully done sentiment analysis on and am now trying to see which words most often contribute to a positive or negative sentiment by plotting the words using ggplot2.

I have this so far:

```
dtm_sentiments %>%
  count(sentiment, term, wt = count) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(n >= 200) %>%
  mutate(n = ifelse(sentiment == "negative", -n, n)) %>%
  mutate(term = reorder(term, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(term, n, fill = sentiment)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ylab("Contribution to sentiment") +
  coord_flip()
```

But keep getting error code:
Error in count(., sentiment, term, wt = count) : unused argument (term).

Does anyone have any ideas on why this error is occurring?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you're using `count` correctly. Can you post some representative (& minimal) sample data?

Comment: I cannot upload the actual text files I am using but here is a link to some sample text files http://www.textfiles.com/adventure/. I am essentially using the code given in this text mining book I found (https://www.tidytextmining.com/dtm.html) but adapting the code somewhat for my job descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Using the sentiments data in the tidytext package and tweaks to your code,we have:

```
   sentiments %>% 
  count(word,sentiment) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(n >= 2) %>%
 mutate(n = ifelse(sentiment == "negative", -n, n)) %>%
  mutate(word= reorder(word, n)) %>%
  sample_n(45) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(word, n, fill = sentiment)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ylab("Contribution to sentiment") +
  coord_flip()
```

This gives the following plot:
 [image]
Although I'd think a wordcloud would be better.

Comment: Used `sample_n` as filtering would return too many values which would take a lot of time to obtain a plot.

Comment: Thanks, Nelson, for the help! When I ran your code I got the following the error: Error in UseMethod("as.quoted") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "function". My sentiments object looks like this for reference:                                               
     # A tibble: 75 x 4
       document term        count sentiment
       <chr>    <chr>       <dbl> <chr>    
     1 3        absence         1 negative 
     2 3        affirmative     1 positive 
     3 3        ambiguous       1 negative 
     4 3        available       1 positive

Comment: Could you add sample code and/or `dput(head df)`. It might be easier to follow. As I see it seems you data is a term document matrix. Maybe convert this to a list or dataframe? It's hard to know.

Comment: As `typeof(sentiments)` is a list in this case.

Comment: Hi, Nelson. My data (df_sentiments) is in a tibble with 4 columns: document, term, count, sentiment. I have essentially been following the instructions as listed in [https://www.tidytextmining.com/dtm.html], where this example also creates this sentiment plot from a tibble.

Comment: # A tibble: 75 x 4
       document term        count sentiment
       <chr>    <chr>       <dbl> <chr>    
     1 3        absence         1 negative 
     2 3        affirmative     1 positive 
     3 3        ambiguous       1 negative 
     4 3        available       1 positive 
     5 3        awards          1 positive 
     6 3        benefits        1 positive 
     7 3        best            4 positive 
     8 3        capability      1 positive 
     9 3        commonplace     1 negative 
    10 3        competitive     1 positive 
    # ... with 65 more rows

Comment: It's hard to know why your code isn't working. However the error suggests there's an unused argument "term", did you tidy the data as suggested using the `tidy` function from the `broom` package?